# Get info of Exception details

Tags: c#, exception

I want to write methodname,classname,filename,linenumber of the exception. How can I Achieve this? I tried the below code, passing `Exception` to the function which writes `msg` in text file.

```
string msg = "";
StackTrace st = new StackTrace(ex);
var frame=st.GetFrame(0);           
msg = @"Message : " + ex.Message + " \n FileName: " + frame.GetFileName() + " \n Method Name : " + frame.GetMethod() + "\n Line Number : " + frame.GetFileLineNumber()+"\n Class Name :"+frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType;
```

Log written in file as below

```
 Message: Message : Attempted to divide by zero. 
 FileName:  
 Method Name : Void Page_Load(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
 Line Number : 0
 Class Name :RequestsView
```

Why `FileName` is missing and `LineNumber` showing 0 even it occurs at another line on the page. Please suggest the correction in code if any.

Comment: Try printing information for all the frames rather than just the 0th one.

Comment: Please check answer to [StackTrace filename unknown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650253/stacktrace-filename-unknown) question.

Comment: for efficient error logging with all your above requirements use ELMAH http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Exception.StackTrace` property of thrown exception to get all information you need

Answer (score 0):

Why try to reinvent the wheel? DRY. NLog offers this functionality and much more straight out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line to get the details you want..

int lineNumber = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex,true).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber();
className = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex, true).GetFrame(0).GetFileName();
methodName = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex,true).GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name;