# Track down queries called from Entity Framework code

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Is there a way in entity framework to track down or determine where the ad hoc queries were called from in code?  This query is from the Activity Moniter in SQL Server, however I can't tell where it came from in our code, we have a ton of calls.  Is there a way to figure this out easily?

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [Test].[DT] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM  [Test].[D] AS [Extent2]
            INNER JOIN [Test].[ME] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[EId] = [Extent3].[EId]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[DId] = [Extent2].[Id]) AND ([Extent3].[MId] = @p__linq__0)
        )
    )) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41414784/861716

Answer (score 1):

For EF Core this is the reason the [Query Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tags) feature was added, or you can always use  [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging).  For EF6 you can use [logging and interception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception).

Comment: Awesome but this isn’t EF core