# EF Core - Producing unfiltered queries on all members of dbcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, datacontext

I'm writing this here, in the hope that someone has experienced this before and has a thorough answer to this problem.

We have a C# Web API that handles CRUD operations where we are using EF Core as our ORM to manipulate data.

From inspecting the SQL logs we can see that there are many select statements that are unfiltered (no where clause). That don't seem to be coming from the code base.

What is strange about this is some of the tables that are being called have no other references in the code other than being on the DBContext itself.

For example.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext{
    public DbSet<MyDbSet> MyDBSet { get; set; }
}
```

This seems to periodically output a select statement on the table even if its not used in the code.

```
SELECT [m].[Id], [m].[Column1], [m].[Column2]
FROM [MyDBSet] AS [m]
```

The problem with this is, that some of these tables have large amounts of data in which I would like to avoid an unfiltered query.

From further inspection it seems that the order in which these unfiltered queries occur is the same order they are found on the DBContext.

Example 2

```
public class MyContext : DbContext{
    public DbSet<MyDbSet> MyDBSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MyDbSet2> MyDBSet2 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MyDbSet3> MyDBSet3 { get; set; }
}
```

```
SELECT [m].[Id], [m].[Column1], [m].[Column2]
FROM [MyDBSet] AS [m]

SELECT [m].[Id], [m].[Column1], [m].[Column2]
FROM [MyDBSet2] AS [m]

SELECT [m].[Id], [m].[Column1], [m].[Column2]
FROM [MyDBSet3] AS [m]
```

This happens even when the table is not read or referenced in the codebase, and there are no references to these tables that don't have a where clause.

My first assumption is that EF core is taking a snapshot of the table? Perhaps query caching or something similar?

I guess my question is, does anyone know what could be causing such odd behaviour and or is there something in EF core that is responsible.

NOTE - We are not using Lazy Loading Proxies package and are using eager loading throughout the application

Comment: Do you have EF logging enabled?

Comment: Serilog? Which EF Core version? If 2, do you have client evaluation disabled?

Comment: Do you use [AsSplitQuery()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#split-queries-1)?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft no EF logging enabled EF core version is 3.1

Comment: @AndrewSilver No - seems like the queries are coming from EF as the way they are crafted with the explicit aliases

Comment: @ErikEJ we do have serilog that writes to a blob storage container

Comment: Do you have a (minimal) repro? Yes, queries are executed by EF Core, but definitely are not initiated by EF Core, but some client/3rd party library code.

Comment: @IvanStoev not really the system is very large and I would not be able to share anything specifically - I am just wondering if anyone has seen this before? judging by the Aliases it seems to be EF. Also found that this Github issue also describes the problem, however it supposedly was fixed. 
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/5738

Comment: @JamieD Hey, this is issue from EFC v1, and also a preview, not really a release. EFC currently is v6, and v7 is coming soon (what version are you targeting btw?). I'm watching all their public releases and I'm pretty sure the calling code is not from EFC. Minimal repro doesn't mean to share code from a real system, just a small, but fully working code snippet(s) which can be copy/pasted in a clean new project, compiled and ran and reproduce the issue (even though if you can do that, you'll probably find  the cause :-) There is no EF Core code which runs "periodically".

Comment: @IvanStoev we are currently on 3.1.6 - and are on .NET core 3.1 (we intend to upgrade) but this cannot be done until we understand this problem. The unfiltered queries happen on a series of tables (no hand crafted code is doing this) - as there are millions of records in those tables, our Azure instance is killed and all of our users struggle to access the system.

Not able to reproduce this locally, we have a large volume of users on our production system too

Comment: As described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41414784/find-out-which-code-run-entity-framework-sql-code), you can log every `SELECT` being executed - including the stacktrace, and then find out what's the app code that executes the redundant selections.

Comment: @OfirD thank your for getting back to me, however I find your response slightly blunt and lacking in completeness. For the interest of brevity, please respond with how you would output the stack trace of all queries in EF core 3.1

Comment: @Jamie my bad, the post I linked to doesn't refer to .NET Core. To implement global logging in .NET Core EF (specifically EF 3) you can use the [answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62988857/3002584), which links to a very elaborated article that I recommend. Let me know if this one works for you.

Comment: @OfirD I am aware of adding logging as mentioned in the article above, however this does not include the stack of the calling code

Comment: @Jamie, wait, you mean you already set up the logging middleware, and use `new StackTrace().GetFrames()` where needed, but still can't see what stack frame executed the `SELECT`?

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but are you certain these queries are coming from your application? You could check via the user name of the connection.

Comment: Look for ToList/ToArray, or in general, materializing statements! :) To me it sounds like some code is materializing the results before filtering (in process/memory).

Comment: I think you are using **ToList()** before **where** . It is possible to put one of the queries here

Answer (score 1):

After scrutinising a significant memory dump of the system - The package that was causing the reported unfiltered queries was Serilog.

https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Serilog.Exceptions

From here you will find the following details around versions of Serilog exceptions and it appears that being on below version 8 in conjunction with EF core, caused Serilog to try and destructure values that implemented `IQueryable` - in newer versions this does not happen.

WARNING: In versions of `Serilog.Exceptions` older than 8.0.0, if you are using Entity Framework Core with `Serilog.Exceptions` you must add this, otherwise in certain cases your entire database will be logged! This is because the exceptions in Entity Framework Core have properties that link to the entire database schema in them (See #100, aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore#15214). Newer versions of `Serilog.Exceptions` avoids this issue by preventing the destructure of properties that implement `IQueryable` preventing their execution.